# .htaccess - shorten url string

Tags: .htaccess

I'ld like to shorten this link. I think .htaccess is the solution fo this, right?

```
http://www.example.com/myfolder/?option1=hello&name=world&land=how&location=are&city=you
```

How can this be managed?
Thanks

Comment: Shorten this URL to what? Do you have a desired target URL for the above?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achive is this

http://www.example.com/hello/world/ => http://www.example.com/myfolder/?option1=hello&name=world&land=how&location=are&city=you

right?

If so, you can use htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)?\/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)\/?$  /app/index.php?option1=$1&name=$2
```

The use is somehow complicated, but the idea is:

if somebody open the URL: http://www.example.com/first/second/

the first: `([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)` 'captures' the word 'first'

the second: `([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)` 'captures' the word 'second'

and then converts to `/app/index.php?option1=first&name=second`

Check this article for more info http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

I'm using [a-zA-Z-_0-9] because the url can contain letters, numbers and underscore. You can select the characters you want.

Comment: One thing that I forget to mention. I'm using the string that comes after "?option1=" to load content from a file. Does this still work if the url gets a rewriting from `example.com/myfolder/?option1=myrandomstring` to `example.com/myfolder/myrandomstring` ?